# Rollup configuring alias for semantic-ui-less @import

Tags: rollupjs, semantic-ui-react, fomantic-ui

I have been configuring rollup for creating custom react component library on top of fomantic-ui.
I have already setup the **rollup.config.js**
ALthough in the configuration, I need to resolve an import:

```
@import (multiple) '../../theme.config';
```

the import is part of fomantic-ui-less library, which needs to be resovled to:

```
path.join(__dirname, '/themes/theme.config')
```

and I do have **themes/theme.config** at my project root.
when I run build command it throws following error:

```
[!] (plugin postcss) Error: '../../theme.config' wasn't found. Tried - E:\Projects\UILibrary\node_modules\fomantic-ui-less\theme.config,..\..\theme.config
```

and I have used the **rollup-plugin-postcss** plugin and **@rollup/plugin-alias**, and called it inside plugins array

```
...
plugins: [
...
alias({
entries: [
find: '../../theme.config$',
replacement: path.join(__dirname, '/themes/theme.config')
]
})
postcss(),
...
]
```

I have also tried changing the order of plugins.
And the worst part is, it is working when configuring the storybook, using webpack alias.

```
.storybook/main.js
```

```
webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      "../../theme.config$": path.join(__dirname, "../themes/theme.config")
    }
...
}
```